# How to Display Scroll, Like and Video on Header on Wordpress Post when Open from Facebook App?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

When I check other site, it opens in facebook built-in browswer, with scroll, comment, like, share and video play on the top of the header:

[image]

However, when I open my site, it looks different, event my content is the same as them. I don't find video on the header, scroll navigating page on the top, and comment like share at the bottom.

But they both open in Built-in facebook app browser.

We both using Wordpress with the same theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an instant article which we have to apply via Facebook. Thanks.